# How to receive complete data from serial port in linux

Tags: c++, linux, serialization

I am trying to do a  serial communication application. I have a device which is running angstrom qt linux image. I need to write the serial code application for that device. Because the cross compiler is set for QT4.8.7, so it do not include the `QSerialPort`. So I am following this [link](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) for serial communication and I have also found many good examples on it.

Below is the code:

```
void MainWindow::SerialOpen(QString PORT)
{
fd = open(PORT.toStdString().c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1)
{
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyLP0\n");
    exit(1);
}

saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
saio.sa_flags = 0;
saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC );

tcgetattr(fd,&termAttr);
cfsetispeed(&termAttr,B9600);
cfsetospeed(&termAttr,B9600);
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
termAttr.c_cflag |= CS8;
termAttr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
termAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
termAttr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
termAttr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&termAttr);
qDebug("Serial Port configured....\n");
}
```

and for reading I am using:

```
void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{
  char buf [100];
  int n = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf);
  if(n > 0)
  {
    buf[n] = '\0';
    printf("Receive OK %s\n",buf);
  }
}
```

I am using event based serial read. I am wiriting it in QT creator. The problem I am facing is that whenever I am sending characters like `A` or `B` or any other single char. It receives it. But when I send the complete string, it breaks automatically. Have a look at the below image:

[image]

As you can see in the image, it receives char like `p` `l` `h` but then I sent `hello world`. It breaks it and first received `hello` and then `world`. I again sent the `hello world` it receives the `he` then `llo` then `worl` and then `d`. Why is this showing this behaviour.  Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving your data in small chunks. Try running the `read` function in a while loop to append all chunks into one message like so:

```
#include <cstring> // needed for strcat.
#include <errno.h> // needed for strerror and errno
void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{
    char buf [100];
    char msg[1024];
    int n;
    int length = 0;
    while((n = read (fd, buf, (sizeof buf)-1)) > 0)
    {
        buf[n] = '\0';
        // you can add a check here to see if (length+n) < 1024
        strcat(msg, buf);
        length += n;
    }
    if(n<0)
    {
        //error handling
        //EDIT: adding error handling
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while receiving message: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    printf("Receive OK: '%s'\n", msg);
}
```

<del>The signal handling needs to be turned off for the time of reading data so that the signal handler doesn't get called for each new chunk of data. After we're done reading the handler needs to be restored.</del>
**EDIT**: Thanks to @MarkPlotnick for giving a better example on masking the signal instead of turning it off (could cause race condition). Add these two lines before calling `sigaction` to `MainWindow::SerialOpen` to mask the signal so that the handler doesn't get called again while the signal is being handled:

```
sigemptyset(&saio.sa_mask);
sigaddset(&saio.sa_mask, SIGIO);
```

The size of `msg` is just an example, you can set it to any value that will fit the message. Also, if you're using c++ then it would be better to use `std::string` instead of an array for `msg`.

Note the `(sizeof buf)-1`, if you read all characters there would be no room for the `'\0'` at the end of the array.

**ANOTHER EDIT**: After our chat conversation it turned out that `read` is blocking when there are no more characters to read (even though `open` was called with `O_NDELAY` flag for non-blocking reading). To fix this issue one can first check how many bytes are available for reading:

```
while(true)
{ 
    size_t bytes_avail; 
    ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_avail); 
    if(bytes_avail == 0) 
        break; 
    int n = read (fd, buf, (sizeof buf)-1); 
    if(n<0) 
    { 
        //error handling
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while receiving message: %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
        return; 
    } 
    buf[n] = '\0'; 
    // you can add a check here to see if (length+n) < 1024 
    strcat(msg, buf); 
    length += n; 
}
```

Comment: @CZAbhinav Thanks for the quick heads up :)

Comment: @Rogus It didnt print anytthing on the terminal. Not even the recive ok

Comment: That means `read` returned -1. Hold on let me add the error handling @SAndrew try now

Comment: It still didnt worked. I am also editting it. Will update it if it works

Comment: @SAndrew Does your first version work? Maybe the `read` keeps blocking?

Comment: @Rogus My first version. I didnt get you. I have posted everything what I have done in the question. And I want to know that can we directly read the file `/dev/ttyLP0` and save all its content in a variable because afterall `read` is also trying to do the same. Can we do that.

Comment: what I meant by first version is the function you posted, without my edits with the `while` loop. I wanted to know if your function still works because if it does then something is wrong with my version (but I don't know what, if something was wrong someone would probably point it out by now). But if your version also stopped working then you must have changed something in your code.

Comment: No the first version which you posted didnt worked too

Comment: Your first version not mine, from your question not from my answer. but I think I know what's wrong, hold on let me make another edit to my answer

Comment: @SAndrew try the new version :)

Comment: @Rogus It didnt worked but can you explain about new things you added. And yes the version I posted in my question was working.

Comment: @SAndrew I added the description with my changes right below the code. Can you check how many times does your signal handler get called? In `gdb` or quickly add a `printf` at the beginning. Also try moving the first `sigaction` in the handler with `oldact` to the beginning right after `{` so it is the first thing that gets called.

Comment: @SAndrew I made a mistake with ignoring the signal. It wasn't ignored, it just fetched the signal currently used. Now there is an ignore added to the signal, please try this version :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141875/discussion-between-s-andrew-and-rogus).

Comment: To block SIGIO in the signal handler, it may be safer to do `sigemptyset(&saio.sa_mask); sigaddset(&saio.sa_mask, SIGIO);` before the call to sigaction in `MainWindow::SerialOpen`. That way, you don't have a race condition trying to ignore the signal in the signal handler before the signal potentially comes in again.

Answer (score 0):

> QT4.8.7, so it do not include the QSerialPort

You can build QSerialPort from sources and to use it. Please read Wiki: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port

Comment: from where can I get QSerialPort sources. At this step `Build and Install from QtCreator` the first point mentioned is to download the QSerialPort sources but there is no downlodable file provided at the link which they have provided.? From where can I get the QSerialPort source